# is there a shortcut for print function in pycharm which is similar to sout in intellij

Tags: python, pycharm

Is there something similar to sout which is in in intellij for java. I am looking for something similar which will do the print function for python in pycharm. Like a shortcut which will write print() in pycharm.

i tried looking online and wanted to see what others are using.

Comment: You can alias print yourself just by writing e.g. `sout = print` (thus saving one character of typing per print command).

Comment: @khelwood I believe OP is asking for an IDE-level alias, not a language-level one.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, there is a shortcut for `print()`: `.print`. It works exactly the same as `.sout` in IntelliJ: Type an expression, a dot, then `p`. The shortcut should be shown somewhere in the popup.

[image]